# Python - MYSQL dynamic query: Insert values into table syntax

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python, dynamicquery

I am using Python and mysql (import mysql connector).

I was trying to insert multiple values in a dynamic column, which I created before. However, something is messed up with the syntax of my query and I am not able to write it correctly.

What is working (not dynamic as an example): -> In Column ynoqxzvb, value '1c' is added.

```
                  conn.cursor()
                  select4 = """ INSERT INTO oldcards (ynoqxzvb) VALUES ('1c'); """
                  cursor.execute(select4)
                  conn.commit()
```

What I want to do is (dynamic):

```
                  select5 = """ INSERT INTO oldcards (%s) VALUES (%s); """
                  tple = (str(RouteID),str(mydict[ID1]["Card1"]))
                  cursor.execute(select5,tple)
                  conn.commit()
```

So basically I want to have the columnname and the inserted value dynamic using the local variables "RouteID" and "str(mydict[ID1]["Card1"])".

The error code is:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ynoqxzvb') VALUES ('Card2=4b')' at line 1
```

Does somebody know the correct syntax?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: mysql does not support dynamic query i think

Comment: You can't pass  a column or a db  object name as   a variable

Comment: It does support dynamic query and you can also make the column name dynamic. Its just that I didnt manage to do it with multiple arguments in one query yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct, because the names of the columns do not correspond the values you are trying to insert.
Assume `str(RouteID)` is 1 and `str(mydict[ID1]["Card1"]` is 2.
Then `cursor.execute(select5,tple)` translates your query into

```
INSERT INTO oldcards (1) VALUES (2)
```

What you actually want is:

```
INSERT INTO oldcards (column1, column2) VALUES (1,2)
```

Where `column1` and `column2` are the names of the columns you want to insert into.
So the correct way would be:

```
 select5 = """ INSERT INTO oldcards (column1, column2) VALUES (%s, %s); """
 tple = (str(RouteID),str(mydict[ID1]["Card1"]))
 cursor.execute(select5,tple)
 conn.commit()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is exactly not whart I want to have. My goal is to make the column name and the inserted value both dynamic.